# List products in descending order

Tags: number-theory

I'm doing a problem from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) where I need to examine a descending order of multiples of 3 digit numbers

```
Obviously 999 * 999 is the largest 3 digit product
How do I know without doing the multiplication whether 999 * 997 or 998 * 998 is larger
```

Is there a way to know what the next largest 3 digit * 3 digit product is?

Comment: Yes. Because $(n+1)(n-1) = n^2-1 < n^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full list can be computed in a few seconds in *Mathematica* this way:

```
Reverse@Union[Sort[Flatten[Table[i j , {i, 0, 999}, {j, 0, 999}]]]]
```

What do you want to examine in that list?  Clearly $999 \cdot 998$ is the second-largest element in that list.

Comment: This is a solution that someone submitted in Python that is Big O(n^2). https://projecteuler.net/thread=4;page=9#last I believe that the OP wants to iterate through that array finding the largest products first, checking if each is a palindrome and thereby returning the answer in the most efficient way possible. What is the Big O for the Mathematica solution?